# How can I use pandas explode, crosstab and count number of occurence for large dataset? (7MM rows)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, crosstab

I have a large dataset of 7 millions rows and 2 columns. However, the second column contains a list of different cases. The number of cases will be quite consequent ( after running my algorithm for 10 000 first rows I found 27k+ cases ).

Here is a sample representative of what I have and the result I am looking for:

**My initial dataframe:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["id", "listElements"])
df = df.append([{"id": 1, "listElements": ["apple","peer", "[apple, peer]", "banana", "chocolate", "[chocolate, apple]"]},
{"id": 2, "listElements": ["ginger","peer", "[ginger, sugar]", "tofu", "[tofu, veggie]", "chocolate", ]},
{"id": 3, "listElements": ["steak","beef", "[beef, potatoes]", "banana", ]}]

)

print(df)
#  id                                       listElements
#0  1  [apple, peer, [apple, peer], banana, chocolate...
#1  2  [ginger, peer, [ginger, sugar], tofu, [tofu, v...
#2  3            [steak, beef, [beef, potatoes], banana]
```

**My end goal:**
For each element (or group of elements), get the number of occurence and the id where it is happening.

**What I do now:**
explode the second column, then use crosstab like so:

```
df2 = df['listElements'].explode()
df = df[['id',]].join(pd.crosstab(df2.index, df2, colnames=['listElements']))
print(df)

#which gives me:
#  id  [apple, peer]  [beef, potatoes]  [chocolate, apple]  [ginger, sugar]  ...  chocolate  ginger  peer  steak  tofu     
#0  1              1                 0                   1                0  ...          1       0     1      0     0     
#1  2              0                 0                   0                1  ...          1       1     1      0     1     
#2  3              0                 1                   0                0  ...          0       0     0      1     0
```

Then I am thinking of aggregating the results to obtain the count for each type of element and keeping the id for later investigations.

**My problem:**
The data has around 7 millions rows and I would suspect around 100 000 types of elements!

I am pretty sure my computer will run out of memory with such a dataset and/or it will take a very long time to process!

**2 questions:**

1. Is there a more straight forward, quicker way to produce my result (maybe I am doing some non necessary steps?)
2. How can avoid memory or speed problems? Can I maybe speed up the algorithm by transforming the elements to numbers? Or run it in batches before to join the result?

Any insight is very welcome!!! If something is not clear please don't hesitate to ask me for more info!

Comment: So your expected output has 7m rows * 100k columns = 700 billions cells. Assuming each cell take 1 byte, that's gonna take ~650GB of memory. Do you need to perform analysis on such a big data frame at once?

Comment: I was seeing more a end result as a matrix with 100k rows for the keyword then, the count of occurrence for each and à list of id in which they appear in the last column! That is why I am wondering if I am not doing an extra step...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider working with a long, not wide representation. Here is a [convtools](https://github.com/westandskif/convtools) based example:

```py
from convtools import conversion as c


input_data = [
    { "id": 1, "listElements": [ "apple", "peer", "[apple, peer]", "banana", "chocolate", "[chocolate, apple]", ], },
    { "id": 2, "listElements": [ "ginger", "peer", "[ginger, sugar]", "tofu", "[tofu, veggie]", "chocolate", ], },
    { "id": 3, "listElements": [ "steak", "beef", "[beef, potatoes]", "banana", ], },
]

# generated ad hoc converter function; run on startup and reuse further
converter = (
    c.iter(
        c.zip(
            c.repeat(c.item("id")),
            c.item("listElements"),
        )
    )
    .flatten()
    .pipe(
        c.group_by(c.item(1)).aggregate(
            {
                "ingredient": c.item(1),
                "ids": c.ReduceFuncs.Array(c.item(0)),
                "count": c.ReduceFuncs.Count(),
            }
        )
    )
    .gen_converter()
)

result = converter(input_data)

assert result == [
    {"ingredient": "apple", "ids": [1], "count": 1},
    {"ingredient": "peer", "ids": [1, 2], "count": 2},
    {"ingredient": "[apple, peer]", "ids": [1], "count": 1},
    {"ingredient": "banana", "ids": [1, 3], "count": 2},
    {"ingredient": "chocolate", "ids": [1, 2], "count": 2},
    {"ingredient": "[chocolate, apple]", "ids": [1], "count": 1},
    {"ingredient": "ginger", "ids": [2], "count": 1},
    {"ingredient": "[ginger, sugar]", "ids": [2], "count": 1},
    {"ingredient": "tofu", "ids": [2], "count": 1},
    {"ingredient": "[tofu, veggie]", "ids": [2], "count": 1},
    {"ingredient": "steak", "ids": [3], "count": 1},
    {"ingredient": "beef", "ids": [3], "count": 1},
    {"ingredient": "[beef, potatoes]", "ids": [3], "count": 1},
]
```

Also it makes sense to obtain a dict to easily query it by ingredients:

```py
converter = (
    c.iter(
        c.zip(
            c.repeat(c.item("id")),
            c.item("listElements"),
        )
    )
    .flatten()
    .pipe(
        c.group_by(c.item(1)).aggregate(
            (
                c.item(1),
                c.ReduceFuncs.Array(c.item(0)),
            )
        )
    )
    .as_type(dict)
    .gen_converter()
)

result = converter(input_data)
assert result == {
    "apple": [1],
    "peer": [1, 2],
    "[apple, peer]": [1],
    "banana": [1, 3],
    "chocolate": [1, 2],
    "[chocolate, apple]": [1],
    "ginger": [2],
    "[ginger, sugar]": [2],
    "tofu": [2],
    "[tofu, veggie]": [2],
    "steak": [3],
    "beef": [3],
    "[beef, potatoes]": [3],
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! I will try your solution asap, it looks great!

Comment: Hi westandskif! Your solution seems a lot faster indeed! I was just wondering if it is possible to make it work in the case where my inner list of ingredients are inputed as    "['tofu', 'veggie']" instead of "[tofu, veggie]"... I had to scrap again my data and ended up with this format, whn I now try your code it struggles with this new format : (

Comment: hi @JeremieHouet, if I understood correctly, you now have real lists instead of strings in complex component cases. Then it should be failing because lists are not hashable. Please, check this gist -- it's updated the code above for the input I've assumed - https://gist.github.com/westandskif/362930891265815c474d37400108d603

Comment: You are my hero 